# I'm unable to access SharePoint Server through unc

Tags: alternate-access-mapping

We're running a SharePoint Server 2010 in windows 2008 server. Earlier we use to map SharePoint site to a drive and access the files. For the past few days we're unable to map the drive or access through unc. But we are able to access the site through internet explorer. Do we need to change the configurations to access the SharePoint site through unc or map drive? Please suggest!

Comment: What's changed? Where are you trying to access from(client or server)?  there is no special server config or SharePoint setting.  Could be privation firewall, network, or client configuration problem.  Please add as much detail as you can to the question.

Comment: We're trying to access from client system. When I try to map to the drive, after inputting the credentials for 4 times it gives the following error message. "Windows cannot access \\servername\sites\projects. Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems, click Diagnose Error Code: 0x80070035 The network path was not found. I've tried even accessing through unc. I'm able to access the site through url but not through unc or map network drive

Comment: I am able to access a shared folder from the server through unc or map network drive but not sharepoint site.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has it's own implementation of WEBDAV - you don't need that enabled on your IIS server. Also you need to ensure the clients have the webclient service started.

To rule out networking across devices, I would attempt to access this from another server (may require installing desktop experience feature to get webclient service installed) - if it works here, then you will need to investigate the network connection between your clients and server - you may have an application firewall or similar inspecting and blocking this type of traffic.